# iOS record video first frame is black

Tags: ios, video-recording

I'm made a record video app, but the first frame always be black.

I use:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

and assetWriter to write sample buffer.

I found that the first sample buffer is mediaType:'soun', does it is the problem.

How should I do

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. And I think first sample buffer being "sound" should be the problem. What I tried to do is to ignore the first sample buffer if it's sound. Wait until the first "video" sample buffer comes in and then do the AVAssetWriter startWriting thing. I solved my problem by doing this.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too. I think, this answer should be marked as the best.

Comment: Just vouching for this as the correct answer as well. Should be marked as answered!

Comment: It didn't work for me. I don't have the microphone connected, so I'm not getting sound sample buffers. All buffers have the same type (CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType) and subtype (CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType). What else to try? Thanks.

Comment: Don't startSession until you get a video frame -- ignore all audio data until then.  Then make sure the start time is zero, and adjust it if it's not.

Comment: @drewster can you post a sample of how to ignore the audio? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002615/avfoundation-first-frame-from-recorded-mix-composition-video-is-black

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply @ethanchli, it helped me, so I decided to add some details.

First, try uninstalling the AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate extension if you are not using it, because it runs the same function with AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate extension.

`func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){}`

Or if you need audioSamleBoofer :)

Try this - Check orientation support which exist only in video connection.

```
    if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
        // Work with video samle boofer
    } else {
        // Work with audio sample boofer audio
    }
```