# AVFoundation -First frame from recorded mix composition video is black

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I record a video or a series of video clips using AVFoundation. I patch them all together using an AVMutableComposition. Sometimes the first frame in the resulting video is black. I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26656091/4833705), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28138818/4833705), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32345115/4833705) which all point to the same issue.

The problem seems to occur when sound is written before video.

> make sure the first thing you write to the file is a video frame and
> don't write any audio until after the first video frame is written,
> you won't have any black frames

**How do I ignore the sound before video is written?**

```
var assets = [AVAsset]()

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    let asset = AVAsset(url: outputFileURL)
        
    assets.append(asset)
}

func mergeAssests()

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                               preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
    
    let soundtrackTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio,
                                                         preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    
    var insertTime = CMTime.zero
    
    for videoAsset in assets {
        
        do {
            
            let arrOfAssetTracksWithVideo = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
            if !arrOfAssetTracksWithVideo.isEmpty {
                
                try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                           duration: videoAsset.duration),
                                                           of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                                                           at: insertTime)
            }
            
            let arrOfAssetTracksWithAudio = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)
            if !arrOfAssetTracksWithAudio.isEmpty {
                
                try soundtrackTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                     duration: videoAsset.duration),
                                                     of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0],
                                                     at: insertTime)
            }
            
            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAsset.duration)
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // send mix composition to AVAssetExportSession ...
}
```

Comment: @SPatel what do you mean? You lost me

Comment: Please verify your audio track length is same as video

Comment: What do I do if it isn't? Or better yet if the audio is longer

Comment: if its grater then you need to reduce audio duration

Comment: Can you post an answer so I can try it out? The problem is it happens randomly and doesn't happen at all with iPhone without a notch. Notch iPones cause the issue

Comment: In simulator or real device?

Comment: real devices, I have an iPhone 7+ and the black frame issue never occurs but with an iPhone X it happens randomly ]

Comment: @SPatel what do I do if the audio is longer than the video? I'm assuming I'd have to cut the first part of the frame that is longer but how do I compare both track lengths and then cut the part of the audio that is longer?